# How to set different role of node in INET like MiXiM

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, inet, mixim

Omnet++ 5.0 and INET 3.4

I want to simulate a MAC protocol base BMAC, however, nodes in the net topology have different function. So I set a enum called **role** in .h file and add several **handlemsg** function in .cc file
like below codes in the MiXiM

```
    //in .cc file add 
     enum ROLES {
        NODE_RECEIVER,      // 0
        NODE_SENDER,        // 1
    };
    ROLES role;

   //in .h flie add
   void XXXMacLayer::handleSelfMsg(cMessage *msg) {
   // Check role of this node
        if (role == NODE_SENDER) {
           handleSelfMsgSender(msg);
        } 
        else {
           handleSelfMsgReceiver(msg);
        }
    }
```

however, there is a warning "Member 'role' was not initialized in this 
 constructor"
Anyone can give me some advice or some examples to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Refer to the [manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/inet-manual-draft.pdf) for examples and more details.

Comment: Thank you！@Rens van der Heijden     But could you be more specific？ Actually I don't know where to start find something related in manual

Comment: A simple warning issue is not 'Too Broad' I vote to reopen. If duplicated or any other issue, please, trigger the correct flag